# Set multiple request header in javascript

Tags: ajax, es6-promise

Is it a good practice to use `setRequestHeader` twice like below? I need to use `X-Requested-With` in order to get some HTML forms.

```
function formRequest (method, url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open(method, url);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    client.onload = function () {
      // ...
      resolve(client.response);
    };
    // ...
    client.send();
  });
}
```

Thank you.

By the way, it works with or without the `Content-type`.

Comment: `js` at Question appears to return expected result?

Comment: You can add as many request headers you need, there is nothing wrong with it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`request.setRequestHeader()` Can be called multiple times, each time it is called it will add a new header. Therefore what you have done in your question is correct.

```
client.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

Will cause your request to have two headers.